# Remove string's portion from the start until certain word

Tags: php, regex

I have a string :

```
$s = "I am not foo+bar";
```

I want to remove the first portion of `$s` **starting from the beginning of the string until the word `"foo+"`** so it becomes "<strike>I am not foo+</strike>bar" :

```
$s == "bar"
```

How can I achieve that with PHP?

**Edit :** I have a "+" sign inside the string. Why `preg_replace` is not replacing it? The pattern that I've used is `/^(.*?\bfoo+)\b/`. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work? Have you had a look through the php string functions? Particularly str_replace and strpos - http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: I did but I can't figure out how can I include the word "foo" in the portion that I want to remove!

Comment: Can't really help too much without seeing the code you've tried. Update the question with some of the code you tried that didn't work. An alternative might be to use explode with spaces as your delimiter  to split the string into an array, compare each element in the array then implode the rest back into a string.

Comment: Was mentioned already that you need to escape `\+` from it's special regex meaning as a quantifier. I think you could simply use [`$s = explode(" foo+", $s)[1];`](https://eval.in/581088) here if you don't need any regex functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a regex to find everything up until a certain word. For your example,

```
/^(.*?\bfoo)\b/
```

Should work with `preg_replace`.
 The `^` makes sure we start at the beginning of the string.
 `.*?` is anything (excluding new lines add the `s` modifier to allow new lines as well) until the first `foo`.

> Simply put: \b allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of \bword\b. A "word character" is a character that can be used to form words. All characters that are not "word characters" are "non-word characters".

-http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/gJ3nS7/3

Rough untested replacement example using `preg_quote`.

```
preg_replace('/^(.*?\b' . preg_quote('foo', '/') . '\b/', '', $s);
```

Longer example the `+` is a special character but also is a non-word character so the `\b` won't work trailing that. You can put the `+` into an optional grouping with the word boundary and that should work.

https://regex101.com/r/gJ3nS7/5

```
/^(.*?\bfoo(?:\+|\b))/
```

Comment: You don't need to use regex for everything. Also, the question asks for the position of "foo", not "bar"

Comment: @RobbieAverill okay, invert that word. Regex is still needed. Per your answer you don't find the first instance of `foo` as a word, https://eval.in/580864.

Comment: Then look for `foo` with spaces on either side instead, you don't need regex :) https://eval.in/580865

Comment: @RobbieAverill Won't work if the word is at the start or end of the string (no whitespace would be present) Not to mention punctuation marks

Comment: Fair enough :) I could go through the rigmarole of proving that you don't "need" regex to do this, but I can't be bothered now. You have my vote.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you take a look at my update please?

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi You need to escape the `+`. The `+` is a special character in regex; it means one or more of the previous character/group (in your case one or more `o`s, which you don't want). You also could use preg_quote which would handle the quoting of all special characters in your word. Added an example using the `preg_quote`.

Comment: @chris85 How to escape the `+` inside this pattern?

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi To escape it would be `\+`.

Comment: Actually nope, that breaks the word boundry, will need an alternative approach.

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi Yea, two different issues were occurring, I think `^(.*?\bfoo(?:\+|\b))` will work. https://regex101.com/r/gJ3nS7/5

Comment: @chris85 Doesn't seems to work with PHP `preg_replace`. Error `No ending delimiter '^' found`. It replace te totality of the string!

Comment: The regex is `^(.*?\bfoo(?:\+|\b))` the delimiters are still needed. Make it `/^(.*?\bfoo(?:\+|\b))/`.

Comment: @chris85 Still not replacing the `+` :s

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are saying, https://eval.in/580876. Update your question with your actual code.

Comment: Yea, an exact example from the start would have been useful. You can use the `i` modifier so case doesn't matter. That goes after the closing delimiter.